# Home network visibility

Tags: networking, router, nas, home-directory

I am setting up a network in my house and I am facing a problem. I cannot access my home NAS server that is currently under the second router from PCs that are connected to the main router, this image describes my problem:
[image]

Everything that has address 192.168.1.x I cannot access from computers connected to 192.168.0.x router, is there any solution or the NAS server has to be simply connected to the main router to be visible from all the PCs connected ?

The PC that si marked red in the picture has no problems with visibility of NAS server.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to have two different subnets in your network?

Comment: Put the second router in bridge mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually do want to have two subnets for some reason, you're going to need to do something like:

- Set up a static route to 192.168.1.0/24 via the second router's 192.168.0.x IP on the main router
- Turn off NAT on the second router OR do a port forward to the NAS' IP on the second router

As it is right now, your main router has no idea how to get to 192.168.1.0/24, so it's sending it out over the WAN to your ISP, where it gets summarily dropped.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not have a technical reason for having two subnets, the fix is easy.

Each of your routers is performing NAT, and each has its own subnet, which is not what you want. Instead of using the second router as an actual router, just use it as a switch. Disable its DHCP and routing functionality and then use its switch (all of the non-WAN ports) to connect to the rest of your network and to other devices near the second router.